# Searching ppa for recent versions of git and cmake

Tags: ppa, git

I am searching for two PPAs for a Lucid Server.

One for git, I found [Git stable releases](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa) for Git, is this correct? I did not find any PPAs for cmake and need support for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa is the correct place for the git stable PPA.

As for cmake, I'm not sure there's an official PPA for that... but if you have a look at the bottom of this link, you'll see some PPA's that do exist for it: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cmake

Comment: I find only backports as PPA, that is too much, I only want to have cmake. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested, you can easily find PPA's for packages by visiting this link: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=&show_inactive=on

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is still finding this (as it's quite high up in the google ranks) - there is a PPA for the newest cmake version (for 12.04, though):

https://launchpad.net/~kalakris/+archive/cmake